I want to know R2 value wrt Vin and Vout of HCNR201 circuit
I'm trying to learn this circuit, it is HCNR201 (Source - HCNR201 High Bandwidth Evaluation Board User Guide). I want to calculate value of R2 w.r.t. Vin, Vout and HCNR supply. Specially trying to get exact formula. 

If we assume the output of U2 goes to ground, then the datasheet will have the LED specs so calculating R2 is Ohm’s law.

There isn't an exact formula, because the circuit uses diodes all the equations describing it are non-linear and hard to derive (can't use linearity or frequency equations). You can make some assumptions with closed-loop values and the output on each diode is matched (closely) so the output on vout will match vin.
